# Ionic2/Angular2 - Doesn't wait for return

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I try to call my provider to get last transactions from Firebase Database, but the assignment doesn't wait for the return of the function.

As you can see, in the console, I first got **'undefined'** (from the *console.log()* in *home.ts*) and the **'Got auth'** with my correct auth object from the *'transaction.ts'* provider.

I based myself from this Github answer : https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/708#issuecomment-269012111 but the problem is that my assignment doesn't proc, and I don't know why.

Some of you have a idea ?
Thanks

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AddTransactionPage } from '../add-transaction/add-transaction';

import { Transaction } from '../../providers/transaction';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  lastTransactions;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private transaction: Transaction) {

  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.lastTransactions = this.transaction.getLastTransactions();
    console.log(this.lastTransactions);
  }

  public addTransaction(): void {
    this.navCtrl.push(AddTransactionPage);
  }

}
```

**transaction.ts (provider)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class Transaction {

  constructor(public http: Http, private angularFire: AngularFire, private auth: Auth) {
  }

  public getLastTransactions(): any {
    this.auth.getUserData().subscribe(auth => {
      console.log('Got Auth', auth);
      let transactions = this.angularFire.database.list('/users/' + auth.auth.uid + '/transactions').map(transactions => {
        return transactions.map(transaction => {
          transaction.category = this.angularFire.database.object('/categories/' + transaction.category_key); //Getting category from another collection
          return transaction;
        });
      }).subscribe(data => {
        return transactions;
      });
    }, error => {
      console.log('Error', error);
      return null;
    });
  }

}
```

**auth.ts (provider)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AngularFire, AuthMethods, AuthProviders } from 'angularfire2';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class Auth {

  user: any;

  constructor(public http: Http, private angularFire: AngularFire) { }

  public getUserData(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.angularFire.auth.subscribe(auth => {
        if(auth)
        {
          this.user = auth;
          observer.next(auth);
        } else {
          observer.error();
        }
      }, error => {
        observer.error();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not returning observable in getLastTransactions function. You have to do  the same as in getUserData();

Comment: Oh god, I'm so stupid. Thanks a lot !